# How to parse a template that has variables from a formatted string?

Tags: templates, go

I have a struct with two fields. The Msg string will be fmt.Sprintf("%s %s"), and I need to parse templates to those two variables in the string

```
type DataDB struct {
    ID  int
    Msg string
}
```

Trying to parse template here, and the expected result should be -
Hello Justin, my name is abc

```
    var name = "justin"
    var msg = "abc"

    justin := DataDB{ID: 1, Msg: fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", name, msg)}
    s := []DataDB{justin}

    tpl, err := template.New("msgs").Parse(` {{range .}}
     Hello {{.name}}, my name is {{.msg}}
     {{end}}
     `)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, s)
```

Comment: You can't, at least not in any sensible way. Why don't you add a `Name` field to the `DataDB` type? For example: https://play.golang.com/p/akpFiMJuKJo

Comment: ... otherwise you would have to take `Msg` string, parse the two values apart and then use them in the template. Or you would have to write a template function that takes a string, splits it, and then outputs one of the values based on some indicator, like an index for example.

Comment: @mkopriva I used just two fields in my strict, because I’m meant to execute a query to the db with just two columns. That’s why I used just an id, and a message of type string with two values. Is there a way to parse the two values in my string?

Comment: If you know the format of the message, and it's constant across all the rows in the db table, then yes. For example if the message is always two values separated by a space character and the values themselves don't contain space then just use `strings.Split(msg, " ")` and the result will be a slice containing both values which you can then access by indexing into the slice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `DataDB` struct doesn't have a name field, so you won't be able to reference it in your template.

Update your template to be the following:

```
type DataDB struct {
    ID  int
    Name string
    Msg string
}
```

and then set a name in your declaration

`justin := DataDB{ID: 1, Name: name, Msg: msg}`

Now you can reference the `.Name` field in your template

```
tpl, err := template.New("msgs").Parse(`
    {{range .}}
    Hello {{.Name}}, my name is {{.Msg}}
    {{end}}
`)
```

Finally, when referencing fields in templates, the fields need to be exported, so they should all start with an upper case letter. See my version of the DataDB struct above.

EDIT, you don't need the `fmt.Sprintf(...)` now.

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U6Bn-azNrK5)

Comment: the reason there are only two fields in my strict, is because I’m supposed to have a database with just an id and a message. If you separate the message, how can I execute the db then? I used a string so I can pass 2 values in the message.

Comment: In that case then as @mkopriva commented under the OP, you will need to split the `.Msg` field in the template using a template function. From the question, I'm guessing you would need to split on the space character.

You can acheive this by passing in a `FuncMap` to your templates `Func` method 
Func method: https://godoc.org/text/template#Template.Funcs
Template Func Map: https://godoc.org/text/template#FuncMap

Comment: I used just two fields in my strict, because I’m meant to execute a query to the db with just two columns. That’s why I used just an id, and a message of type string with two values. Is there a way to parse the two values in my string?

Comment: Then you should split the result string of your query from the `msg` column

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `Msg` contains `Name + " " + Message`, so you need to **split** it on `" "`.

Go templates are logicless. But you can use helper functions to add logic.

For example:

```
type DataDB struct {
    ID  int
    Msg string
}

func (d *DataDB) Name() string {
    return strings.SplitN(d.Msg, " ", 2)[0]
}

func (d *DataDB) Message() string {
    res := strings.SplitN(d.Msg, " ", 2)
    if len(res) < 2 {
        return ""
    }
    return res[1]
}
```

And use them in the template like this:

```
{{range .}}
    Hello {{.Name}}, my name is {{.Message}}
{{end}}
```

[Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/LQS21Jc5kA-)

---

Note: the code above is slightly inefficient because it does the splitting twice, so it might be better to create a separate `struct` just for display purposes and fill it before rendering the template.